# How to setup Bitbucket Pipelines for Laravel test and SSH Agent to deploy on a remote server

Tags: laravel, ssh, server, bitbucket, dockerfile

I am developing a project in laravel 5.4. I have repository on Bitbucket. Now I want to setup Bitbucket Pipelines so I can test when anybody commit. I think I need a suitable Docker Image for laravel, I tried some images but they generate errors. Also I want to setup SSH key agent so Whenever I commit in production branch it deploys on server.

I searched a lot on internet to do these things but I could not find anything, If you share any detailed tutorial or something like this it will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."  Please read through that guide.

Comment: Bitbucket pipelines won't be free of charge anymore so be aware!